# Design a DFA that accepts language L={ x in (0,1)* | the third bit from x from its right end is 1}

Tags: finite-automata

this is very confusing question. I am having no idea to solve it, can you please guide me here?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, your solution should be posted as an Answer, not as an edit to the Question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is the answer. We are basically tracking the last 3 bits. eg in 001 we get 0 then last 3 bits will be 010. That's all.